# Update Custom UITableViewCell UILabel after asynchronous Parse query

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

*Can't think of a good name for the question...if you can think of a better one, please feel free to edit it :)*

I am building an iOS app using **Swift** and **Parse.com**.

In my app, I have a main `PFQueryTableViewController` which loads some data from my Parse cloud into some custom UITableViewCells.

One of the values that I want for a label on the cells takes a while for Parse to return and so I am getting it using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock()`.

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when I'm loading my table, I have the following code:

```
// Set cells for each row of table
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

    var cell: CustomTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // Get Course Object objectID to hand to getCourseGrade function
    var anObjectID: String = object!.objectId!

    cell.setCell(name: object!["objectName"] as! String, code: object!["objectCode"] as! String, grade: getObjectGrade(anObjectID))

    return cell

}
```

In the code above, I am calling a function called `getObjectGrade` to pass a value across to my `setCell()` function which sets up the customTableViewCells as it builds the `UITableView` which runs as below (simplified):

```
func getObjectGrade(objectIdString: String) -> Float {

    // Set a starting value of objectGrade
    var objectGrade: Float = -1

    //...I set up a PFQuery

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        //...here I am retrive the value I need from Parse --> valueFromParse

        objectGrade = valueFromParse

    })

    return objectGrade

}
```

**NOW**, I am VERY AWARE that this will NOT work...obviously the code does not wait for my `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock()` code to run and so returns the `objectGrade` before it has been updated.

**MY QUESTION:** How could I set the value of the label of my cell once the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock()` code section DOES complete?

Comment: @Kutyel, that question is totally different. I am not having trouble getting the data from Parse, I am unsure how to set a Label value of a Custom Cell after an asynchronous function. The key also is that I need to maintain the reference to the cell...that's the tricky part.

Comment: If you are doing a process in background, then don't rely on the return statement. I believe in this code `block` will be executed once the download is complete, so call another helper method which can trigger the cell update and do so on main thread(find an equivalence in parse).

Comment: Yes Gandalf thanks :) Solved now! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I moved the "getObjectGrade" function to my CustomTableViewCell file and called it from there. :) If anyone has this issue and needs help, just comment and i'll try :)